# Aligning labels with ggrepel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

According to the most recent updates, `ggrepel` now supports `hjust` and `vjust`. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/blob/master/vignettes/ggrepel.md#limit-the-direction-of-label-movement), using this should align all of the labels. However, I'm unable to get the labels to align, as seen below

[image]

I have tried

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:5), y=seq(1:5), label=letters[seq(1:5)])

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=label),
                  force=1, point.padding=unit(1,'lines'),
                  hjust=0,
                  direction='y',
                  nudge_x=0.1,
                  segment.size=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

How can I align these labels?

**EDIT**

I should add that it's not just having the labels aligned, but also having them near each other, with different length connectors in order to facilitate that.

Answer (score 10):

First, as far as I understand, this is only available in the development version. So you need to install it from github:

```
devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")
```

Second, I think this only works for data points with the same x value (for `hjust`) or y value (for `vjust`).

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:5), y=3, label=letters[seq(1:5)])

# not aligned
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=label),
                  force=1, point.padding=unit(1,'lines'),
                  # vjust=0,
                  direction='y',
                  nudge_x=0.1,
                  segment.size=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

```
# aligned bottom
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=label),
                  force=1, point.padding=unit(1,'lines'),
                  vjust=0,
                  direction='y',
                  nudge_x=0.1,
                  segment.size=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

```
# aligned top
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=label),
                  force=1, point.padding=unit(1,'lines'),
                  vjust=1,
                  direction='y',
                  nudge_x=0.1,
                  segment.size=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Damn! I guess I'll wait to see if anyone knows a way to get all of those labels close together. If not, I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html), `hjust` is not supported in the current version (`0.7.0`) on CRAN.

In addition, it seems like your `direction`, `nudge_x`, and `nudge_y` are not associated.

I change your code slightly to the following three versions.

**`direction = 'y'` and `nudge_y = 0.1`**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=label),
                  force=1, point.padding=unit(1,'lines'),
                  direction = 'y',
                  nudge_y = 0.1,
                  segment.size=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

**`direction = 'x'` and `nudge_x = 0.1`**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=label),
                  force=1, point.padding=unit(1,'lines'),
                  direction = 'x',
                  nudge_x = 0.1,
                  segment.size=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

**`direction = 'both'`, `nudge_x = 0.1`, and `nudge_y = 0.3`**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=label),
                  force=1, point.padding=unit(1,'lines'),
                  direction = 'both',
                  nudge_x = 0.1,
                  nudge_y = 0.3,
                  segment.size=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

It seems to be working. The only thing I notice is that label `e` seems to be restricted because of the limitation in `x` and `y-axis`, so you may want to further expand the axis as follows.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=label),
                  force=1, point.padding=unit(1,'lines'),
                  direction = 'y',
                  nudge_y = 0.1,
                  segment.size=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 5.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the documentation I linked to is more current than the documentation you linked to. `ggrepel` does support `hjust` and `vjust`. I appreciate the thoroughness of your answer, though.

Comment: Interesting. It seems like the version on CRAN (`0.7.0`) does not support `hjust`, while the version on git (`0.7.1`) supports `hjust`. I am using `0.7.0` and when I ran the code with `hjust` the condole returns `Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: hjust`. Anyway, I think the key is the `direction` and `nudge` argument need to be the same.

Comment: Yeh, I had to download the github version using devtools. I got the same warning you did before.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what exactly your goal here is. If you want all the labels on one side, it may be easier to just draw them manually rather than using ggrepel.

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:5), y=seq(1:5), label=letters[seq(1:5)])

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(x = max(x) + 0.1, y = y, label=label), hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x + 0.04, xend = max(x) + 0.06, y = y, yend = y), size = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]